# Japanese half/full width conversion

Tags: c++, c, glib

I'm facing a character width problem in Japanese using glib::ustring.

I have this string: ウェッジパンプス

I want to convert it to: ｳｴｯｼﾊﾟﾝﾌﾟｽ

Using ustring::normalize, i get this string: ウェッジパンプス (in fact, here, each character with accent fills two characters width)

Is there a standard method to do this kind of processing? Is ICU better at doing this?

I need to convert Japanese strings into one of the two formats because a string in half width is different from the same one in full width.

Comment: @sye042, not a glib specialist, but I have seen that ustring::normalize() has a parameter controlling the normalization.

Comment: Yes, i'm already using it but I don't have the results I want. Seems that ICU is great but I have to change all my code if I want to integrate ICU.

Comment: sye042: Why do you need to 'change all of your code'? You can call ICU's Fullwidth-Halfwidth transliterator from C++ or C. If you are on Ubuntu, isn't ICU already packaged for the platform?

Answer (score 1):

There is LCMapString that can do conversion between half/full width hiragana/katakana

```
AnsiString text = "変換する文字列"; //input text
//変換方法 how to convert
DWORD flags = LCMAP_FULLWIDTH; //全角文字にします。flag to convert to full width
//DWORD flags = LCMAP_HALFWIDTH; //半角文字にします）。to half width
//DWORD flags = LCMAP_HIRAGANA; //ひらがなにします。to hiragana
//DWORD flags = LCMAP_KATAKANA; //カタカナにします。to katakana
const int size = text.Length() * 2 + 1;
char* s = new char[size];
try
{
  ZeroMemory(s, size);
  LCMapString(GetUserDefaultLCID(),
              flags,
              text.c_str(),
              text.Length() + 1,
              s,
              size);
  AnsiString newtext = s; //変換した文字列 converted text
  return newtext;
}
```

ref:

- http://www.gesource.jp/programming/bcb/39.html

Comment: That could work (I don't know), but I think that since the OP mentions `glib` he is not working on Windows.

Comment: Thx but I'm developing under Ubuntu. Is there any equivalent of LCMapString? It seems pretty straight forward to use.